# Accessing AJAX added inputs with JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I have a form that on document load, loads additional fields based on previous selected values on another page. This is all done with JQuery. Rather than posting all my code in here right now, here is a basic mockup on what I am doing...

```
<form>
    <input>
    <input>

    <div id="loadedcontent">
        <AJAX loaded inputs on document load>
    </div>

    <input submit button>
</form>

<script that posts to a PHP file and retrieves the form inputs. They all have ID's. The script also has a form submit listener to process it all.>
```

The problem is in the listener for the form submit, I cannot access the ID's of the previously loaded AJAX elements. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Lets see your code that tries to access the newly added elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your code. It may be that when you attempt to retrieve the Id's loaded by the ajax, the Id's do not exist in the DOM. Sometimes a delay needs to be added to ensure the content exists within the DOM before you actually access it.

```
var i = setInterval(function() {
   //some ajax call on load
   clearInterval(i);
}, 500)
```